# Arcgis Gis :Change Color on clicking Graphics

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, graphics

I have a number of point graphics on a map with different colors depecting some meaning.My query is on clicking any graphic(s) I want to highlight it but if I click again it should revert to its orginal color.
Please provide some inputs.
Env:
Arcgis javascript 3.14

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to highlight a graphic on the first click and if you click it again it should be deselected?

Comment: Ya implemented see solution in first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of these two options:

1) use another Graphicslayer and copy the selected graphic from the original layer to the new "select" layer with a special select symbol.  Fire the "copy to select layer" function on the original layer click event and fire the "remove from select layer" function when you click on any graphic in the "select" graphics layer.

2) Add an attributes to the original graphics layer to indicate if it is selected or not.  e.g. `graphic.attributes.isSelected = true`.  Based on this attribute you can toggle the graphic symbol style to selected or original.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response I have already implemented solution one,I am giving u a tick mark  because your answer is correct Thanks for helping